# How to use string as column name in Bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

There is a scenario where I receive a string to the bigquery function and need to use it as a column name.
here is the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION METADATA.GET_VALUE(column STRING, row_number int64) AS (
(SELECT column from WORK.temp WHERE rownumber = row_number)
);
```

When I call this function as `select METADATA.GET_VALUE("TXCAMP10",149);` I get the value as `TXCAMP10` so we can say that it is processed as `SELECT "TXCAMP10" from WORK.temp WHERE rownumber = 149` but I need it as `SELECT TXCAMP10 from WORK.temp WHERE rownumber = 149` which will return some value from temp table lets suppose the value as `A`

so ultimately I need value `A` instead of column name i.e. `TXCAMP10`.

I tried using execute immediate like `execute immediate("SELECT" || column || "from WORK.temp WHERE rownumber =" ||row_number)` from [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62145107/7406635)  to resolve this issue but turns out I can't use it in a function.

How do I achieve required result?

Comment: while you provided much details related to your problem 0 it is still not clear what exactly your use-case! please explain what it is that you are trying to accomplish. Example of input data and expected output will greatly help us to help you :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and trial-error methods, I used this workaround to solve this issue. It may not be the best solution when you have too many columns but it surely works.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION METADATA.GET_VALUE(column STRING, row_number int64) AS (
(SELECT case 
when column_name = 'a' then a
when column_name = 'b' then b
when column_name = 'c' then c
when column_name = 'd' then d
when column_name = 'e' then e
end from WORK.temp WHERE rownumber = row_number)
);
```

And this gives the required results.

> Point to note: the number of columns you use in the case statement should be of the same datatype else it won't work

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this result with the help of UDF in standard SQL in BigQuery.

But it is possible to do this with stored procedures in BigQuery and EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement. Consider this code, which simulates the situation you have:

```
create or replace table d1.temp(
  c1 int64,
  c2 int64
);

insert into d1.temp values (1, 1), (2, 2);

create or replace procedure d1.GET_VALUE(column STRING, row_number int64, out result int64) 
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || column || ' from d1.temp where c2 = ?' into result using row_number;
END;

BEGIN
  DECLARE result_c1 INT64;
  
  call d1.GET_VALUE("c1", 1, result_c1);
  
  select result_c1;

END;
```

Comment: in my case, there is no guarantee that `result` will be of type Int and looks like I cant use `ANY TYPE` here. I was planning to use this function in a select statement like `SELECT function(dynamically generated column name, rownumber) col1,
SELECT function(dynamically generated column name, rownumber) col2` So even if I prepare stored proc it will be difficult to use.

Comment: I agree that `ANY TYPE` cannot be used in stored procedures. In this case, this solution won't help you. Maybe someone else would come up with a better solution. I'm also interested in this topic :)

Comment: I got a workaround for this. I posted an answer below. Just wanted to inform you as you were interested in this topic.

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. It may be useful in some cases for me too :)